# A Weird Topology on $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

I was thinking about how to construct a topology on $X \times Y$ (cartesian product of sets), where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. The usual product topology aside, this was what I came up with:

> Let $S$ be a subset $X \times Y$. For $p \in X$, write $S_p = \{ q : (p,q) \in S \} \subset Y. $ Define $S_q \subset X$ similarly.
>
> Define the open sets of $X \times Y$ to be sets $S$ such that $S_p$ and $S_q$ are open in $X, Y$ respectively, for all $p \in X, q \in Y$.

I managed to show that this defines a topology on $X\times Y$, and that $(X \times Y) \times Z = X \times (Y \times Z)$.

It is also finer than the usual product topology. For $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example, consider the following sets

- the open (in the usual sense) triangle with vertices $(0,0), (2,-1) , (2,1)$
- the $\pi / 2$ rotations about the origin of said triangle
- the origin.

The union of these sets is open in the $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ sense as defined above, but not in the usual sense.

I have not studied topology in depth, so I have no idea what properties a topology made from other topologies ought to have. So I have a couple questions that i came across while thinking about this. Sorry in advance if some of these questions are a bit soft.

- Is this something that has been studied before?
- Is this a "nice" construction, in the sense that it has useful properties?
- Related to the above: what are the desirable properties of a product topology? Is the usual product topology the only relevant construction?

For the second question, I noted that this topology is not compatible with the affine structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (a $\pi/4$ rotation of the triangle-union-construction renders it non-open). So clearly the topology remembers the axis that was involved in its definition. How come this is not the case for the usual product topology, even though it, too, is defined with respect to some axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been called the *cross topology* and has been studied in connection with functions on $X\times Y$ that are continuous in each variable separately but not necessarily jointly continuous. You can read about it (among others) in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864198000765) by Mel Henriksen and Grant Woods; it’s about 20 years old now, but it’s a place to start and has quite a few references.

The usual product topology is by far the most important. For example, it is characterized by a [useful universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties). It also preserves compactness ([Tikhonov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem)), and compact spaces have a great many desirable properties.

To answer your final question, the product topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is also the topology induced by the Euclidean metric, which is independent of the product structure.

Comment: Thank you for a clear exposition on this topic. Is it true that the product topology always correspond to the metric-induced topology, if X and Y are metric spaces?

Comment: @SecondWind: You’re welcome. Yes, it does.